# How to add a custom message in obiee 11g/12c?

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I have added a new text in l_en/messages/text.xml

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<WebMessageTables>
  <WebMessageTable lang="en-us" system="Test" table="Tests">
  <WebMessage name="kmsgSystemTest">
  <TEXT>Test</TEXT>
</WebMessage>
</WebMessageTable>
</WebMessageTables>
```

But when I try to use kmsgSystemTest, console error says "kmsgSystemTest" is not defined.
Should I declare this new text somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states that custom messages should go in the **customMessages** folder inside

ORACLE_INSTANCE\bifoundation\OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent\coreapplication_obipsn\msgdb\l_xx

(where xx is the language identifier, l_en in your case).

Also don't forget to restart the BI Presentation Services.

Hope it helps

(doc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e10541/webuicustom.htm#BIESG3437))

Comment: Right but just that didnt make the messages accessible.